# Importing JS Data into HTML File Using Script Tags

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

In my Node project I am trying to pull in some data to an HTML file from a JS file. I came across a couple of examples re: how to do this. Here's my question: should the following work?

In my index.html file I have the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/user-interface/jobs-list.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" >
                function load() {
                     const jobsData = JSON.parse(data);
                     console.log(jobsData);
                     }
                 }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
     // ... other code
    </body>
</html>
```

The `jobs-list.js` file I'm pulling in here looks like this:

```
const data = [
    "Job 1",
    "Job 2",
    "Job 3"
];

module.exports = data;
```

In other words, should this be sufficient to get the contents of my array logging to the console when I run the HTML file? If not, what am I missing? I'm just trying to get a basic understanding of how to pull in data from an external JS file into an HTML file when both belong to the same project.

When I try this as is, I get this error in the console of my browser:

`(index):20 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: Where you have `JSON.parse(data)`. If `data` is not defined globally, this will not work. Also if you're not using some kind of transpilation tool, `module` will not be dinefined in the browser.

Comment: So what would be a minimal implementation then -- if, for instance, I was pulling in a straight json file `['job 1', 'job 2', 'job 3']`? How does one pull in data and assign it to a variable in the HTML file?

Comment: If you don't use `module` in the browser, then your code is OK, as long as `data` is global. I would however make the `load` function referentially transparent by passing in the hard coded value of `data` as a parameter. `function load(json) {const jobsData = JSON.parse(json);}` Then, pass the data when load is called, like this: `<body onload="load(data)">`. This is a small change, but now your load function is more portable.

Comment: Thanks. And how does one ensure "data" is global in this case?

Comment: Ideally, nothing. The easiest way is, just `window.data`. But if you're using a transpilation tool, that's going to bring in closures and all kinds of stuff, also if the jobs-list.js is used elsewhere in your Node.js project, window will not be defined, just like module is not defined in the browser.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, and yet, it doesn't seem to work with my current implementation. I would like to know a sure-proof way to - with the simplest implementation possible - pull in external data from another file into an HTML file and use it there. Know any working examples?

Comment: The error I'm getting is: `(index):20 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202019/discussion-between-colecmc-and-ademo).